# Can I "fit" a k-nearest neighbors classifier without precomputing anything?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to fit a KNeighborsClassifier (scikit-learn implementation) to about a gigabyte of training data. From every resource I've read online, a k-nearest-neighbors classifier is a "lazy" classifier in that the fitting process is simply storing a copy of the training data. Then when you make a prediction, you search through the training data to make the prediction.

But when I call fit, it fails, telling me it cannot allocate 800 gigabytes of memory. I believe it's trying to precompute a tree or some type of structure to make future queries faster; but I *don't want this behavior* because it renders the classifier unusable. For my application, I'm okay with slow classifications. I want the lazy implementation.

Is there a way to use a KNeighborsClassifier from scikit-learn without having it use large amounts of memory during the fitting?

Comment: How about downsampling your data first?

Comment: `algorithm="brute"`?

Comment: @BenReiniger I did this and it still attempts to allocate 800 gigabytes when I fit the model.

Comment: Then it's not the query structure you mentioned. The model needs to save a copy of the data; what type of array is your training data, and what type(s) of data does it contain? Provide a code snippet, and the full error traceback.